# postgresql-9.3-pljava-gcj for 64 bit architecture

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, 32bit-64bit, pljava

I need to install pljava for postgresql 9.3 on Ubuntu 14.04. I installed the 64bit version of postgre using the apt-get packet manager of Ubuntu, and I tried installing pljava in the same way

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3-pljava-gcj
```

but it gives me the "unmet dependencies error"

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-9.3-pljava-gcj:i386 : Depends: postgresql-9.3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
```

Apparently, there's no version of pljava for 64bit architectures of pljava for postgresql 9.3. Also searching the Web led me to this conclusion (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/postgresql-pljava/1.4.3-3 - see the "not build" versions of the packet).

Now, my problem is that I have to use a 64bit version of postgresql-9.3, and I definitely need pljava to embed some "java triggering" inside the db. Does anyone know any solution to this issue? Can I use pljava-9.1 with postgresql-9.3? Anything else?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no maintained PL/JAVA package for Ubuntu anymore. The package you mentioned is using a too old version of PL/JAVA, depending on gcj. It is highly recommended to use PL/JAVA version 1.5.0, using a recent Oracle or OpenJDK java version.

The sad news is you have to build it yourself. For instructions, see

- https://tada.github.io/pljava/build/build.html (building)
- https://tada.github.io/pljava/install/install.html (installing)

Answer (score 0):

At the time this question was asked, it was true that there were not maintained PL/Java packages for Ubuntu.

Just to update the story, more recently there are. They can be found in [the PGDG `apt` repository](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt).